# Change the web.config values directly in the app service using yaml

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment-slots

I tried so much to search on this but I was still unclear and there is no post with the requirement as I have.
I'm doing the swap slot using AzureAppServiceManage@0 but after this action, I want to change the values of a few parameters in the web.config, is there a good way of dealing with this?
If I have to trigger a powershell task, it shows the path doesn't exist, how can I directly get to the app service and change the value?

```
- job: swapone
    steps:
      - task: AzureAppServiceManage@0
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: 'subscrip1'
          Action: 'Swap Slots'
          WebAppName: 'xxx-one-swapslottest-67'
          ResourceGroupName: 'xxx-one-rgtest-67'
          SourceSlot: 'staging'
          SwapWithProduction: true
          PreserveVnet: true
```

Comment: Refer my SO thread answer here -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75366490/remove-specific-lines-from-web-config-using-yaml-pipelines/75626944#75626944 I have used Powershell Task to change web.config value

Answer (score 0):

> how can I directly get to the app service and change the value?

You can use [Kudi VFS api](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API#vfs) to `PUT` the file to app service kudu. Need to pass `If-Match: "*"` header in the script.

[image]

For example, I have a web.config on app service kudu:

[image]

I put the newweb.config in repo, and would like to update the dll file name(add test) in argument:
[image]

In DevOps pipeline, add a `azure powershell` task with sample script below, note to get the newweb.config with `-Raw` to keep the xml format.

```
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'ARMConnTest1'
    ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
    Inline: |
      $ResGroupName = "{yourRG}"
      $WebAppName = "{yourappservice}"
      $webConfigFilePath = "newweb.config"
      
      # Get publishing profile for web application
      $WebApp = Get-AzWebApp -Name $WebAppName -ResourceGroupName $ResGroupName
      [xml]$publishingProfile = Get-AzWebAppPublishingProfile -WebApp $WebApp
      
      # Create authorization header
      $username = $publishingProfile.publishData.publishProfile[0].userName
      $password = $publishingProfile.publishData.publishProfile[0].userPWD
      $base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username,$password)))
      #$authHeader = @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo); If-Match="*"}
      $authHeader = @{
      'Authorization' = ('Basic {0}' -f $base64AuthInfo)
      'If-Match'      = '*'
       }
      #$authHeader = @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
      
      # Get the Kudu API URL
      $kuduApiUrl = "https://$($webAppName).scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/site/wwwroot/web.config"
      
      # Read the new web.config content from the file using the Get-Content cmdlet with -Raw
      $webConfigContent = Get-Content -Path $webConfigFilePath -Raw
      
      # Invoke the PUT request to update the web.config file
      Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $kuduApiUrl -Headers $authHeader -Method PUT -Body $webConfigContent -ContentType "text/xml"
    azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
```

[image]

You can find similar answer in ticket [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40827456/invoke-restmethod-how-to-pass-etag-does-not-represent-the-latest-state-of-the).

Comment: But, does it need to have some kind of permission to the app service? My app service has private end point and I'm running it using the hosted agents and I'm getting an error -
##[error]The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found.
And if I run with MS agent pool, it just shows 401 unauthorized. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Yes, the `AzurePowerShell@5` task needs `Azure resource Manager` service connection(ARMConnTest1), it contains the service principal, you need to grant contributor role on app service for this service principal, then it's able to replace the file. And if your app service is configured with private endpoint, you need to use self-hosted agent which has same endpoint, so that the agent can access the app service.

Comment: @devopsseeker, may i know if there's any update? Let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: Actually the script is working, but I'm still getting the 401 (Unauthorized) error. The app service has private end point on and the pipeline is running on a self-hosted agent.

Comment: The 401 (Unauthorized) error could mean the service principal (from ARM service connection) doesn't have permission on the target app service. Please check if it has granted the contributor role. If the issue persists, it's recommended to add the service principal role screenshot, and error screenshot in your description to show more details.